# IPhone earbuds with iPad Pro

Tags: iphone, ipad, ear-phones

Can I use my iPhone 7 earbuds with my iPad Pro 11” 2nd generation, iOS 13.5.1? I’m confused by the lingo about connection ends. Looks like iPhone 7 has Lightning. But I don’t know what the iPad port is called.

Comment: The iPad Pro 2018/2020 ports use a USB-C port. If your iPad doesn’t have Face ID, it’ll work.

Answer (score 1):

Not out-of-the-box.  There are 3rd party adapters that allow this to work.  Belkin, for example, makes a USB-C to Lightning Audio adapter that would work with your current EarPods.  You can also get a USB-C to audio adapter (this would let you use any headphones that have an audio jack -- but not your current EarPods).

The iPhone 7 came with "EarPods with Lightning Connector"

If you check the Apple website on compatibility (for the EarPods), you'll see:

> Works with all devices that have a Lightning connector and support iOS
> 10 or later, including iPod touch, iPad, and iPhone.

The iPad Pro 2nd Generation comes with a USB-C port - it will not work.

Apple provides an excellent document to help you identify the ports on your Mac:  https://support.apple.com/HT201736.  While it doesn't specifically mention iPads/iPhones/etc. it can help you clarify the "lingo" that can get confusing.

Comment: **NOPE!** the "Pro" iPads use USB-C not Lightning. So his iPhone 7 ear buds will not work without an adapter.

Comment: @SteveChambers Which generation of iPad Pro are you referring to. I also think you mean the 3rd generation or later.

Comment: I forgot that this generation now uses USB-C .. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @MacintoshFan let’s not blame Steve for a good answer to a badly worded question. The question would be better if it named products correctly or best if it named the actual connectors. Lightning, USB-C and TRRS 3.5 mm jack are all in play for Apple devices.